# Function expand ssh execution

Tags: bash

As part of a script which runs on another (backup) server I'm trying to write a function which executes random commands remotely via ssh. To keep things simple, I want to keep the existing code mostly as is.

An example what I'm trying to do:

```
function NC_SSH_CMD () {
   cmdArgs=("$@")
   ssh -i root@myserver.intern "bash -s" < ${cmdArgs[@]}
}

NC_SSH_CMD sudo -u "${webserverUser}" php ${nextcloudFileDir}/occ maintenance:mode --on
```

Basically, I want to use NC_SSH_CMD as a prefix for commands which should be run remotely via ssh. Thus the arguments passed should be treated as a remote command with arguments. Though my usage of cmdArgs as an array is the wrong way. It throws the error:

```
${cmdArgs[@]}: ambiguous redirect
```

What's the correct way to pass the command to the function and execute it?

Edit:

There was a bug with the command itself which was unrelated to the question. Since the error was unintuitive I didn't catch it. This works. But is there a better way to handle passing the string to the command?

```
function NC_SSH_CMD () {
   $(ssh root@nextcloud-privat.intern  "$*")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<` operator redirects the contents of a *file* via standard input. To redirect a *string* in bash you'd use a [here string](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html#Here-Strings):

```
function NC_SSH_CMD () {
   cmdArgs=("$@")
   ssh -i path/to/identityfile root@myserver.intern "bash -s" <<< "${cmdArgs[@]}"
}
```

Remember to quote the array expansion `${cmdArgs[@]}` else its elements will be subject to word splitting and possible filename generation.

---

Note that unless `${cmdArgs[@]}` needs to be run in a bash shell specifically, and you know that the remote root shell is something other than bash, you may as well omit the `bash -s` and pass the expanded argument list directly to the default remote shell, as you discovered. However you should use `"${cmdArgs[@]}"` (or `"$@"`) in place of `"$*"` since the latter concatenates the arguments to a single string instead of passing them separately:

```
function NC_SSH_CMD () {
   ssh -i path/to/identityfile root@myserver.intern "$@"
}
```